# how to change position of particular login page image in epsocrm

Tags: espocrm

I have an existing application in epsocrm in which all pages are ready and that all pages have the company logo.

but I have an issue in the login page. the login page has the company logo exactly right side which I want to set in the center.

the example of my login page is given below [image]

I am stuck with finding the solution of this problem. but failed to find

can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need css like this:

```
#login .logo-container {
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```